# BeautifulSoup html table scrape - will only return last row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am attempting a simple scrape of an HTML table using BeautifulSoup with the following:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    sdata = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    return sdata

url = 'http://www.satp.org/satporgtp/countries/pakistan/database/bombblast.htm'
soup = make_soup(url)

table = soup.findAll('table', attrs={'class':'pagraph1'})
table = table[0]

trows = table.findAll('tr')
bbdata_ = []
bbdata = []
for trow in trows:
    bbdata_ = trow.findAll('td')
    bbdata = [ele.text.strip() for ele in bbdata_]

print(bbdata)
```

However, I can only extract the last row in the table, i.e.

```
['Total*', '369', '1032+']
```

All of the data is included in the `trows`, so I must be forming my loop incorrectly, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Notice, for one thing:
>>> bbdata=list(range(3))
>>> bbdata=bbdata.append(5)
>>> bbdata
In other words, bbdata.append(whatever) returns None.

Comment: You probably want **extend**. Like **append** it returns **None**. So you *don't* use it in an assignment statement. You write, say, **bbdata.extend(something or other)** by itself.

Comment: Don't add code from answers to your question, if you have a new problem ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
bbdata = [ele.text.strip() for ele in bbdata_]
```

You want to append to the list or extend it:

```
bbdata.append([ele.text.strip() for ele in bbdata_])
```

You are overwriting bbdata each time through the loop which is why it ends up only with the final value.

Comment: thanks for your comment. When I try to do that, it gives me the attribute error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'`.